# Delphi XE3 Failing to generate new exe file when compiling

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

As title says, when compiling, delphi fails to generate a new exe file, and instead just deletes the old one. This has only started today. Any ideas why?

Comment if you want any more info and I'll add an edit with the extra info!

Thanks!

Comment: do you have write access right on the folder

Comment: @danisius how do I check?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx also try run delphi as Administrator

Comment: Works fine here. Hard to know how we can help. What changed today? Is this for all projects, or just your existing one?

Comment: i faced this issue before , it caused by  anti-virus . check this point .

Comment: @Realbitt Thankyou so much! Just had to turn anti-virus off and it worked. If you want to add this as an answer, I will mark as correct :)

Comment: @Real - Please undelete your answer and disregard the comment to it. It answers the question as it contains the information to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i faced this issue before , it caused by anti-virus . check this point :)

Comment: I disagree, this information led to me solving my problem. It definetly DOES answer my quesiton